# php with ms sql server downloading and connecting

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a project written in php.Also,another application is written in C(sharp) with Ms Sql as the database engine. I want to fetch some data from the Ms Sql database and use it in php. I have tried many solution provided on stackover and other site, but none seems to work.Below are what I have done, maybe there is a place where i am missing something:

I Downloaded drivers(Ms Drivers for php)  and  loads it into the C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext directories.files are

```
php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll
php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
php_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll
php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
```

Modify the php.ini by including the following in the extension  area:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
```

In fact, one of the site says I should rename by removing the "_55_xx", so that it looks like php_sqlsrv.dll.yet it is still not working.

Restart the Apache server and discovered that the included files not activated or seen when you click on the wamp  monitor,navigate to the php and view the extension directory.

I have search and search,seems to be given up, but thought it better to communicate with others who can be of assistance. I currently use wamp and php version is php5.5.12. Please, I need a solution on how to get working drivers to connect my php with Ms Sql server and get data from the server seamlessly.

Comment: um... why are you shouting in title? you think you'll get more exposure?

Comment: @Fred, not at all. I'm sorry, i dont mean to do that for "more exposure". Just wanted a solution, so I didn't take a closer look at that at all.

Comment: @Fred. I currently use mysql for the application. But I want to interface  some fields to mssql server. I have looked into the solution, but none seems to work, that is why I am posting my peculiar issue for assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
After much surfing the solution to the above question is as follows:
1. If you are using wamp server 64bit, you have to downgrade to wamp32bits.
2. Download the microsoft driver for php, essentially the 3.0 version.
3. Install it to your php extension directory
4. Open the php-ini file and add these two files to the extension section of the file:
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
Also uncomment the extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll for usage.
5. Restart the wamp server to proceed.
6. Test your connection using a blank php file with the following code:
<?php

       $serverName = "192.168.1.2"; //serverName\instanceName
       $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"xxxxxx", "UID"=>"xxxx", "PWD"=>"xxxxx");
       $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if($conn ) {
     //echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
  echo "Error in connection";
}
?>
NB: You will need to replace xxxx with your credential. You can also use the Wamp Monitor on the desktop to activate any extension file as well.
```